# ms sql group by column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Cannot group by two tables:

[image]

Output must be:

> Name LastName | 6 (count)
>
> Name LastName | 9 (count)

I tried:

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(person) as groupby_column
 FROM links l
 JOIN persons p
 ON [l].person = [p].id
 GROUP BY groupby_column
```

Comment: You are using `select *` and only grouping by one column. So yes, it will not work !! Have a look at [How to Use GROUP BY in SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the aggregate in the `group by` clause, you specify the columns that make up the (distinct) groups in the `group by` clause. In your case that would be `last_name` and `first_name`.

Plus you have to include all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause so you cannot use `select *` (which is a bad habit to begin with).

Given the desired output you want something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.first_name, 
       p.last_name, 
       COUNT(*) as person_count
FROM links l
 JOIN persons p ON l.person = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.last_name, p.first_name;
```

Comment: perfect, but I already need `id` from table `persons`. And adding `SELECT p.id,` to your code doesn't work. Message:
`Column 'persons.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or t...`
Need table output:
first_name| last_name|count| id of person

Comment: @Jerry1 As I said: any non aggregated column must be included in the `group by`. Just include `p.id` in the `group by` clause and you should be fine (as it is unique per person, it shouldn't change the result)